# What is the recommended way of implementing an NFT sale?

Tags: plutus, nft, marlowe

I'm pretty new to crypto development (I've been a professional software engineer for 5+ years now) and would like to get into NFT development using Cardano.

Currently, I'd like to start a collab with a very talented artist to launch an NFT. The end goal would be a dedicated website where NFTs are sold in batches, whereas the price steadily increases (similar to how the SpaceBudz sale worked).

This seems like a very good project for learning, as I'm more the "learning by doing" kind of person.

I've made my way through all the Cardano Docs, watched a lot of videos, listened to a few podcasts and read even more blog posts, but I'm still very confused about what's the recommended way of implementing such a thing.

Should/can I:

- Use Plutus
- Use Marlowe (not sure if that's even possible)
- Host a Node and interact with it using the CLI/a JS wrapper around it (https://spacebudz.medium.com/how-we-pulled-off-the-sale-9dbe54c30ba5)
- Use an API like https://blockfrost.io/

If using Plutus, I'd probably need to learn Haskell, which would certainly slow things down.

Which route would you take and why?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends.

We finally have smart contracts available so I'd say you go that route if you have some time to commit to learning Plutus.

Or, if you're looking to move fast and get those NFT's out on the 'market' you can go with the approach like SpaceBudz did it.

If you're going with the second approach, here's the URL to the repository:

https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nft-server

It's the implementation for their NFT server, you just need to change few things around, create website, artwork and mint the NFT's.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yea, I think I will probably take the "centralized" route for now and implement it using Node.js/re-using the code of Berry-Pool. Next time, I'll do a deep dive into Plutus which I'm really looking forward to. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fastest is to use nmkr.io they provide APIs and minting and everything you can imagine you’d need!